# Using the tabs in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the tabs with angularjs. And I am loading view dynamically.
What I want is if I have already loaded a view, then with `$state.go` it should not be loaded again and controller should not run again.It should just be set to active.

**View**

```
<tabset> 
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" select="go(tab.route)" ui-sref-active="tab.active" 
  heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled"> 
      <ui-view> </ui-view> </tab> 
</tabset>
```

**JS Controller**

```
$rootScope.tabs = [ { title: 'Dashboard', route: 'store.dashboard', 
         active:true }, { title: 'Home', route: 'store.home' } ]; 

$rootScope.go = function (route) { 
        $state.go(route);
};
```

Comment: Please post your routing logic and html

Comment: <tabset>
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" select="go(tab.route)" ui-sref-active="tab.active" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
    <ui-view> </ui-view>
  </tab>
</tabset>

$rootScope.tabs = [
            { title: 'Dashboard', route: 'store.dashboard', active:true },
            { title: 'Home', route: 'store.home' }
        ];

        $rootScope.go = function (route) {
            $state.go(route);
        };

Answer (score 1):

for typescript:

```
let options: angular.ui.IStateOptions = {
  reload: false
};
```

for javascript:

```
var options = {
  reload: false 
};
```

forbid the reload action in $state.go('state', params, options).

Comment: Does that also disable reload if user press CTRL+F5

Comment: no, Ctrl + F5 will force the browser to reload the whole page.

Comment: getting that error
Failed to instantiate module store due to:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'IStateOptions' of undefined

Comment: node: this is for angular-ui-router, the options should be set to the third parameter of the $state.go function.

Comment: @AliNafees sorry, that is a typescript code. seems you are using javascript. check for the javascript version.

Comment: @AliNafees i think you got the answer?